# Different View between Android Studio and AVD

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new in Android Studio.

By using `dp`, I heard that any machine has the same layout, but when I actually used it, the layout of each AVD were different. Some buttons come out and some buttons hide under the screen. In addition, the layout shown within Android Studio (i.e. in the xml file) and the screen shown in the AVD were different. Why is this happening? Do I know something wrong?

Comment: In the title, VMD is a miswritten AVD.

Comment: You can edit your own post whenever you want.

Comment: Post what you have tried with code or example image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your layout size in android studio preview should match to screen size of AVD.
2. Do not use absolute height and width for each component  such as,

   ```
   android:layout_width="30dp"

   android:layout_height="40dp"
   ```

   Instead use,

   ```
   android:layout_width="match_parent/fill_parent/wrap_content"

   android:layout_height="match_parent/fill_parent/wrap_content"
   ```
3. When you use absolute height and width such as 30dp or 40dp, components will be shown differently on each screen size and they may go outside of screen also
4. You can also use padding,margin and gravity for component position.

Answer (score 0):

> By using `dp`, I heard that any machine has the same layout

No, it's not guaranteed that they have the same layout. By using `dp`, the size (width or height) is almost same in spite of the difference of display density among them.

Comment: So Using "dp" doesn't mean it's going to be perfectly same, but to what extent same?

Comment: @나영윤 The official document (https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities#TaskUseDP) says: *One dp is a virtual pixel unit that's roughly equal to one pixel on a medium-density screen (160dpi; the "baseline" density).*

Comment: So on Android, do I have to use "wrap_content","match_parent" only to look the same on all machines? It's practically impossible to look the same in every machine, right?

Comment: @나영윤 It depends. By using `dp`, you can get virtually a same size **item** for all devices (ex. a same size `FloatingActionButton`). But, if you want to get virtually a same **layout**, put aside sizing in `dp` and design your layout with such nesting-`LinearLayout`s or  a `ConstraintLayout`. With these layouts, each items are defined in relative positions to each others.